Comparing unitaries which are perturbatively close
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and let $H_0$ and $H_1$ be two Hermitian operators on $\mathcal{H}$.  Thinking of $H_1$ as a perturbation of $H_0$, the Duhamel formula allows us to write $e^{-itH_1}$ as a perturbation of $e^{-itH_0}$ as follows:
$$
e^{-itH_1} = e^{-itH_0} + \int_0^t e^{-i(t-s)H_1} (H_1-H_0) e^{-isH_0} ds.
$$
Iterating this identity, one can formally write down an expansion for $e^{-itH_1}$ with the first
two terms as follows:
$$
e^{-itH_1} = e^{-itH_0} + \int_0^t e^{-i(t-s)H_0} (H_1-H_0) e^{-isH_0} ds + \dots.
$$
Define $T_1(t)$ to be this second term, so that
$$
T_1(t) := \int_0^t e^{-i(t-s)H_0} (H_1-H_0) e^{-isH_0} ds.
$$
My question is whether $T_1$ actually controls $e^{-itH_1} - e^{-itH_0}$ in the sense
that for some absolute constant $C$,
$$
\sup_{|t|<1} \|e^{-itH_0} - e^{-itH_1}\| \leq C \sup_{|t|<1} \|T_1(t)\|_{op}.
$$
Above I use $\|A\|_{op}$ to denote the operator norm on $\mathcal{H}$.
I actually conjecture that the estimate above is not true -- it seems like too much of a miracle to ask one term in an asymptotic expansion to control all of the remaining terms.  That said, I could not find a counterexample.

Yes, this is true. The keyword to search for is "operator differentiable functions", see here for example: https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/40744 (since $f(x)=e^{itx}$ is operator differentiable, that shows $|f(H_1)-f(H_0)|\lesssim |H_1-H_0|$, but your claim also follows because $T_1$ is actually the derivative applied to $H_1-H_0$).

Thanks for the tip.  The inequality $|f(H_1) - f(H_0)| \lesssim |H_1-H_0|$ I don't think implies my inequality because $|H_1-H_0|$ could be much larger than $|T_1(t)|$ (there could be cancellations in the integral).  And my understanding is that $T_1(t)$ is only the derivative evaluated at $H_0$, the right hand side does not control the derivative elsewhere as far as I can tell.

It's both: $T_1$ is the (Frechet) derivative at $H_0$ [which is a linear operator $B(H)\to B(H)$], applied to $H_1-H_0$.

It is not in general true that $|f(1)-f(0)| \leq |f'(0)|$, which is essentially the analogue of the inequality I want.  Here $f(s) = e^{it[(1-s)H_0 + sH_1]}$, so $f'(0) = T_1(t)$.  Perhaps there is some additional structure I'm missing about the function $e^{itH}$ but so far that's not clear from what I've read about operator differentiable functions.  Maybe you can spell out in more detail how to get $T_1$ on the right hand side instead of $H_1-H_0$?
